# Display/Not Display JavaScript Alert depending on results of LINQ query

Tags: javascript, asp.net, linq, alert

I am trying to develop code in C#/LINQ (CodeBehind) and JavaScript (in .aspx) that will test to see if a value being added to the database is already there. My goal is to avoid a system error message, halt processing, and display an Alert indicating that the value attempting to be added is a duplicate value. It appears that the code I'm using fires the JavaScript first (i.e. before my LINQ query checking for a duplicate). I'm therefore never getting an accurate read on the LINQ query. `tbxChannel` contains the value to be added to the database. Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm using VS 2010 and My code is as follows:

**LINQ/C#:**

```
var getChannel = (from c in db.Channel
                  where c.Channel1 == tbxChannel.Text
                  select new { c.Channel1 }).ToList();

if (getChannel.Count > 0)
{
    string tbxDupChannel = getChannel[0].Channel1;
    return;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
if (document.getElementById("<% = tbxDupChannel.ClientID %>").value.length > 0)
{
    var dupChannel = document.getElementById("<% = tbxDupChannel.ClientID %>").value;

    window.alert("Update Aborted... " + dupChannel +
    " is already on the database and cannot be added a second time.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: In what method is your C# code executing in your code behind cs file? Also, is your JS waiting for the page to be loaded (i.e. is it inside `$(document).ready()`)?

Comment: your local variable tbxDupChannel is not available in the context you're trying to access it, and you're using it like if it was a control, when it's a string? what are you trying to do here? - why tbxDupChannel.ClientID ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

LINQ/C#:

```
// Make DupChannel a public property
public string DupChannel { get; set; }

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
var getChannel = (from c in db.Channel
                  where c.Channel1 == tbxChannel.Text
                  select new { c.Channel1 }).ToList();

if (getChannel.Count > 0)
{
    DupChannel = getChannel[0].Channel1;
    return;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var dupChannel = '<%= DupChannel %>';
if (dupChannel.length > 0)
{


    window.alert("Update Aborted... " + dupChannel +
    " is already on the database and cannot be added a second time.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Lars, Thx... I'm getting the same result (i.e it works if I click on the save button (ButtonGo) a second time). To answer your questions... My CodeBehind method is in a Save button. My JS is in $("#divButtonGo").click(function (). My intention was: 1. Enter a (key) value in a textbox. 2. Click on the ButtonGo (Save) button. 3. Query the db to see if the value is already there. 4. If there, halt C# processing and pop an Alert. 5. Stop JS processing. My thinking is that this will let the user know that the value cannot be added a second time, and avoid getting a system generated error.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and was able to solve my problem by embedding the JavaScript Alert into my CodeBehind:

```
if (getChannel.Count > 0)
{
    string dupChannel = getChannel[0].Channel1;

    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Update Aborted... \n \nChannel " + dupChannel + " is already on the database and cannot be added a second time.');</script>");

   tbxChannel.Text = "";

   tbxChannel.Focus();

   return;
}
```